# Gesture Recognizer not responding to tap

Tags: swift, uikit

I am newbie
Studying a tutorial from Apple.https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1

I do everything as a guide. I understand that it is out of date.
But why is Gesture Recognizer not responding to tap

I added a check mark to "User Interaction Enabled"

Tell me what to fix in this code so that the Gesture Recognizer responds to tap

```
    //MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
        guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }
        
        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
        photoImageView.image = selectedImage
        
        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Actions
    
    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // Hide the keyboard.
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        
        // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        
        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        
        // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have/lost the connection to the `@IBAction`. You need to connect it once again. Find the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the storyboard and control drag to the `UIViewController` subclass and create an action again, add the code there and delete the old method.

1. Find tap gesture in storyboard and control-drag from it to `UIViewController`.

[image: Tap gesture]

2. Create the `@IBAction` in the `ViewController`

[image: @IBAction]

You could also do it programmatically. Here's how:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tappableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_:)))
    tappableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```